# How can I find the derive tight asymptotic bounds on the following recurrence

Tags: asymptotics, recurrence-relation

$$T(n) = 2 T(n/2) + \sum_{k=0}^n (k+2)^2$$
I want to use the substitution method. How can I generate my guess and how can I determine the growth of summation in the recurrence?

Comment: How on earth did you think that [tag:computer-architecture] was appropriate here? I'm honestly curious.

Comment: Welcome to Computer Science! What have you tried? Where did you get stuck? We do not want to just hand you the solution; we want you to gain understanding. However, as it is we do not know what your underlying problem is, so we can not begin to help. See [here](http://meta.cs.stackexchange.com/q/1284/98) for tips on asking questions about exercise problems. If you are uncertain how to improve your question, why not ask around in [chat]?

Comment: Hint: Simplify the sum. Then use standard methods.